# How can I stitch commits from two git repos together when one was improperly copied from the old one?

Tags: git

I worked at a certain job for a while, created a new monolithic project which had a git repository with a lot of commits. I left this job for almost a year, in which a student developer continued some work. I just returned to this job to find that the old repo, instead of being forked, was just copied file-by-file and init-ed as a new git repo from there. There are now 20-30 commits on top of that.

How do I go about fixing this situation, combining the two commit histories? I am not git-fu expert in any manner and I'm having a hard time understanding how to start tackling this. I haven't even verified that the last state of the old repo matches the beginning of the new repo, and that there may be some uncommitted work in between.

I *think* that rebasing seems to be part of the solution, but I think there's more to it than that.

Rebasing would allow me to do the following:
A -> A2 -> A3
B -> B2 -> B3
into
A -> A2 -> A3 -> B -> B2 -> B3

Has anyone dealt with a similar problem before?

Comment: History, in a Git repository, is the commits in the repository: nothing more and nothing less. Commits, once made, *cannot* be changed: commit `B` is a root commit (has no parent) and will always be that way. So you can't get what you described. What you *can* get, that might be good enough, is to have three "new and improved" *replacement* commits B', B2', B3' that are like B,B2,B3 but different in that B' links back to A3, B2' links back to B', and B3' links back to B2'.

Comment: If that's sufficient, search SO for questions about splicing together commits with `git replace` and then using filter-branch or filter-repo to make the replacements permanent. This has been done hundreds of times before and there are at least a half dozen questions about it. The answers that refer to `git replace` are the ones to use.